# Applying Language Specific Analyzer Dynamically before Solr Indexing

Tags: solr

I want to index multi-lingual data. I can identify the language of any field by Solr's Language Detection. Now how can I apply language specific analyzer dynamically to that field? I do not want to create language specific fields (Like: content_en, content_hi etc.). I want to apply language specific analyzer to same field in run time...

I am new in Search Technology. Can any one help me out?

Regards,

Sagar Majumder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a separate Solr core for each language.
That's what I did and it was very elegant and practical solution.

Comment: Thanx mbonaci.. I will try this..Can u suggest me any tutorial for separating solr core for each language??

Comment: Here is a presentation that could help you make the decision whether to go with separate cores: http://www.slideshare.net/lucenerevolution/steve-kearns-multilingualsearcheurocon2011

Comment: And here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin is the info on how to setup multiple cores. When you finish with that you only need to change analyzer settings for new core to reflect that language. Then, in your app. you simply use current_language setting as a solr query url param.