# Solr indexing approach

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

I'm having a scenario where i have to build multilingual index. specially for two scripts , these two scripts are totally different (Hindi and English). so their stemmers and lemmatisers dont affect each other. My indexing will be huge containing millions of documents.
from follwing 3 which approach do i use for indexing?? :

1. Single field for two languages. 
   advantage - a) as scripts are different i can use both analysers on it. b) faster searching because fields will be limited. c) will need to take care of relevancy issue.
2. Language specific fields : a) possibly slower searching because of many fields.
3. multicore approach : a) problem in handling multilingual docs. b) administration will be hard. c) language specific search will be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest separate cores. IMHO, it's simply the right way to go.

You don't have to use Solr's automatic language recognition, since you define analyzers (lemmatizers/stemmers) for each core/language separately. 
The **only** drawback is boilerplate config elements (most settings are the same for both cores).

See this recent, similar post:

[Applying Language Specific Analyzer Dynamically before Solr Indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585630/applying-language-specific-analyzer-dynamically-before-solr-indexing/8590713#8590713)

Comment: thanks mbonaci, i dont know the language of data that i am going to index. is there any way to dynamically detect language and choose correct core ????

Comment: Language Detection: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Detecting+Languages+During+Indexing

Comment: Thanks mbonaci. I checked for this language detection. but it is not correctly detecting language. the accuracy is less than 10% in my case . even it seems that it is not using fallback field. for all english content it is detecting language which is not white listed . It should detect only white listed languages and if white listed language is not matching the it should fallback to fallback language.  any other pointers for using langdetect apart from wiki. please suggest?????

Comment: Sorry, but I've never used language detection in Solr myself. I always know which language is coming towards me when I index, so I know which core to use.

Comment: I have decided to use first approach, just i have to take care of relevancy. now user can query data in any language (From two) . but problem here is that unnecessorily A language data goes from chain of B language data analysers and vice versa. it will increase indexing time.

Answer (score 1):

Please read that: [Apache Solr multilanguage search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811013/apache-solr-multilanguage-search/8812251), that should help.
If a ware you, I would go with option 2 (I'm using that option).

Comment: thanks Fuxi. I think using the approach u suggested , will that slower search due to searching in many fields for all queriess either query is in language1 or language2 ????

Comment: That is possible, however I haven't feel that. Comparing to time spend generating results by Solr parsing them and presenting on the page. You can always query default language first and if you are not getting any hits try alternative language, that however will take more time in sum :)